# MYSQL time based optimization | Joining call dates between tables on phone # & most recent call

Tags: mysql, sql

This job is to transform the function of the below query into one that will execute quickly as our current logic is far to slow, (has an overall 24 + hr run time).  Please note that the respective columns have already been indexed.

The size of our tables are as follows;
Table 1 - 300,000 rows
Table 2 - 15,000 rows

This query matches phone call dates between two tables based on the phone number uid along with closest proceeding date.  The first table (Phone Call Table 1) phone calls are outbound marketing phone calls made while the phone calls from the second table (Phone Call Table 2) contain the same phone number but are in the context of inbound calls made to numbers displayed within our marketing campaigns.  The logic matches the most recent outbound phone calls to the inbound phone call table based on those respective times and UID

The query is as follows;

```
SELECT `Phone Number 2`, `Time of Call` FROM `Phone Call Table 2`
       JOIN 
       `Phone Call Table 1` 
    ON `Phone Call Table 1`.`Phone_Call_Start_1` = 
       (SELECT MAX(`Phone_Call_Start_1`)
              FROM `Phone Call Table 1`
              WHERE `Phone_Call_Start_1` < `Phone Call Table 
2`.`Phone_Call_Start_2`
              AND `Phone Number 1` = `Phone Number 2`
                     ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following SQL:

```
select aa.`Phone Number 2`, aa.`Time of Call`, max(bb.`Phone_Call_Start_1`) as lateststart
from `Phone Call Table 2` aa
inner join `Phone Call Table 1` bb on aa.`Phone Number 2` = bb.`Phone Number 1`
and bb.`Phone_Call_Start_1` < aa.`Phone_Call_Start_2`
group by aa.`Phone Number 2`, aa.`Time of Call`
```